# UICollectionViewCell asynchronous image loading from device using GCD,

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view that needs to display a collection of images whose files are saved on the device.  They are all 600x600 pixels so I thought it would be better to create the UIImage asynchronously on a background thread and then set the `image` property of my `UIImageView` on the main thread.  Below is where I do this in my `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wo-%@", template.fileName];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (image == nil)
            {
                self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                NSLog(@"image named: %@ in nil!", imageName);
            }
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });

    return cell;
```

Every once in a while `image` will be `nil` for one of the cells.  It isn't reproducible and it's not always the same cell/image name.  I was wondering if this has anything to do with using the `UIImage imageNamed:` method or am I using GCD incorrectly?  Any thoughts on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Using imageNamed means the images are shipped with your app's bundle.  There should be very low latency in just loading those directly (even lower after the first load, since they will be cached by UIImage).  You can/should also consider shipping smaller versions of the images, optimized for the device.  Skip the gcd code, just call imageNamed:

Answer (score 0):

For loading image asynchronously "SDWebImage" could be a best solution.

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

just call the following method in your cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```